# Why does ReportViewer image to Azure Blob Image results in an empty source?

Tags: asp.net, reportviewer

I have uploaded some images to Azure blob storage ([sample](http://areadatos.blob.core.windows.net/adjuntos-dev/269315973344.png)) which need to be referenced from a ReportViewer.

Right now, i have an image control bound to the results of a stured procedure that lists a couple images based on some criteria. The SP is outputting the list of images correctly (the sample link being one of them) but all i get from the image control is an empty block wrapping an img with an empty src.

The behaviour is still present even if i hardwire the sample image link into the image control instead of binding it to the query results (Only difference being that i now get a proper image in the Visual Studio preview).

I have tried disabling all proxies, whitelisting my azure blob domain from the default proxy but have met no success.

Right now my app is running on my development machine.

Update:
Hardwiring the sample link into the image control somehow works now, but i am still facing the main issue: databinding the image control to a sp-produced value results in an empty src. Setting the image source to external and the image to [RValues] is still not working. (Setting a text control to [RValues] will output a valid absolute url pointing to the correct image so i doubt that's the problem)

Update 2: The image is showing as a red x on the PDF export

Comment: have you tried referencing an image on another internet location? Just to eliminate the "Azure" part of your question.

Comment: http://placehold.it/350x150&text=test works somehow :/ @astaykov

Answer (score 0):

Your question has nothing to do with Windows Azure.

In order to reference external images into your reports you need to do a couple of things. First of all you have to enable external images in your report viewer control:

```
ReportViewer1.LocalReport.EnableExternalImages = True
```

Also you need to set the source as `external`. And last but not least make sure the reportviewer httpHandler is properly registered with the web.config.

For more information check the [relevant question here](http://forums.asp.net/t/1158725.aspx) and [documentation here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms251661.aspx).

Comment: I forgot to mention that I already had that line in the page init and page loaded events. I imply Azure might be related because I could have misconfigured the metadata or the blob access mode.

Comment: Then trace the HTTP Requests with Fiddler to check what is the difference between getting image from placehold.it and azure storage

Comment: It's a matter of the image uri being directly written in the report definition versus being data bound. Right now I'm writing a LINQ based set of routines that modify the report definition on the fly instead of data binding the images

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Azure Storage SDK to upload the blobs, you're probably not specifying content type. By default Azure Storage assigns `application/octet-stream` to them and serves them using this content type when you access the files via url. ReportViewer doesn't work well with external images served like that.

So when uploading the image, make sure to specify `ContentType` property of the blob.

```
var blockBlob = container.GetBlockBlobReference("your-image.jpg");
blockBlob.Properties.ContentType = "image/jpeg";
await blockBlob.UploadFromStreamAsync(stream);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public async Task SaveFile(byte[] bytes, string feature, string fileName, string tenant)
    {
        CloudBlobDirectory blobDirectory = GetImageStorage(tenant, feature);

        CloudBlockBlob blockBlob = blobDirectory.GetBlockBlobReference(fileName);
        blockBlob.Properties.ContentType = "image/jpeg";

        using (var ms = new MemoryStream(bytes))
        {
            await blockBlob.UploadFromStreamAsync(ms);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Can you provide more context to your answer? Why does it solve the problem?